# [Prometheus]What will happen on the targets in prometheus after they are down and never come back

Tags: prometheus

I have several spark jobs exposed metrics to prometheus.After the jobs have been finished,the targets in prometheus switch into 'down' state.So will the targets exist forever?If not,can I config prometheus how long it is going to delete the down targets?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAFG4.png)

Comment: --storage.tsdb.retention.time: When to remove old data. Defaults to 15d. Overrides storage.tsdb.retention if this flag is set to anything other than default.
So the down state target will keep 15days?

Answer (score 0):

The targets are defined in the [Prometheus configuration](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/). So, as long as you don't change this configuration, the targets will remain there.

However, you can use a [Pushgateway](https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway) to collect metrics from ephemeral processes like your Spark jobs. In this case, your Spark jobs would push their metrics to the Pushgateway while they run, and your Prometheus scrapes the metrics from the Pushgateway. In this scenario, the Pushgateway is configured as a target in Prometheus rather than the Spark jobs directly.

When the Spark jobs terminate, there will be no new metrics from them in the Pushgateway anymore and there will be no dangling targets.